# do we still need bindingsource when there is entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

entity framework plays a role as ORM in between the underlying datasource and UI controls, i'm wondering do we still need to use bindingsource on top of EF?

e.g. 
can i just bind

```
datagridview.DataSource = entity.getdata();
```

instead of

```
bindingsource.DataSource = entity.etdata();
this.datagridview.DataSource = this.bindingsource;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you can directly bind the datasource of the Gridview to the entity result.
But what about following scenarios:

1. Having multiple controls attaching to the same datasource, e.g. List+Detail
2. Navigating in code-behind through the datasource.
   Can be done using "ugly" CurrencyManager but is much nicer through the bindingsource

More here [bindingsource "Remarks" section in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)